# Connecting to multiple GraphQL endpoints from multiple domains in a single react app

Tags: reactjs, react-router, graphql, api-gateway

This is more a arhitecture/design question. I have a Postgres database that holds multiple schemas. Each schema is associated with a GraphQL endpoint. For instance:

```
client1.example.com/graphql/
client2.example.com/graphql/
```

For the frontend I have a single react app. At the moment I need to point the react app to a single graphQL endpoint. What I would like is to have a **single react app** that maps to the **appropiate graphQL endpoint**. For instance:

```
client1.com connects to client1.example.com/graphql/
client2.com connects to client2.example.com/graphql/
```

What is the best way of achieving something like this. Is this possible using the react router or some sort of API gateway.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: just don't hardcode it ... use some window.location prop/value to build address (link in apollo) at runtime

Comment: If possible, would appreciate a small code example

Comment: example for what? 2 lines of code? ...hello ... IDK how/where you're defining address or even if you're using apollo ... just try